# PearMailer, PHP7, and OpenSSL unable to connect to gmail with unknown error

Tags: php, email, pear, php-openssl, pear-mail

I'm building a website, and part of it needs to send emails (one for account password reset links, the other for general user-admin contact). I've been using PearMailer to send emails through a GMail account, and that's worked fine...until now. For some reason, it's stopped sending emails, and it's giving me this very unhelpful error:

```
 [message] => Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error) (code: -1, response: )
```

openSSL is enabled, and all the credentials I'm using are correct (I can manually sign in to that GMail account using them).

This is the code I'm using, where $config holds the account credentials, and the $_POST data is from the Contact Us form (ignore the lack of sanitization on it while I'm developing):

```
    require_once "Mail.php";
        $params=array(
            "host"=>"ssl://smtp.gmail.com",
            "port"=>465,
            "auth"=>true,
            "username"=>$config["mailFrom"],
            "password"=>$config["mailPass"]
        );
        $headers=array(
            "To"=>$config["mailFrom"],
            "From"=>$_POST['user']." <".$_POST["reply-to"].">",
            "Content-type"=>"text/html",
            "Subject"=>$_POST['subject']
        );
        $mail=Mail::factory("smtp", $params);
        $sent=$mail->send($config["mailFrom"], $headers, htmlentities($_POST['body']));
```

It should be sending my GMail account an email from itself, but instead, it's giving me the error I mentioned above. After changing the to and from addresses, no matter what, it still gives me that error. Which is especially strange, since almost identical code is what I've been using to send password reset links, and that was working fine until just now; of course, it too is now failing to connect.

I can't find anything saying Google has changed its settings, and I absolutely haven't gone over the 2,000 messages per day limit that smtp.gmail.com is supposed to allow, so what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

My solution: switched from PearMailer to SwiftMailer, and in that, I'm setting the SSL options `verify_peer` and `verify_peer_name` to false using `$transport->setStreamOptions`. That seems to send mail just fine now. (Without those options disabled, apparently GMail's SSL certificates aren't compatible with newer versions of PHP. Go figure.)

Comment: php does not do ssl verification itself, it relies on the ssl root certificates accepted by the system for this. You need to fix your server.

Comment: Wouldn't the invalid certificate be coming from GMail's server, thereby making it their problem and out of my control to fix? (I don't have very much experience with SSL security, so I could have no idea what I'm saying right now...)

Comment: it could, but the chances are low.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I'm not really sure if this will work for you, try:

```
$params=array(
            "host"=>"smtp.gmail.com",
            "port"=>587,
            "auth"=>true,
            "username"=>$config["mailFrom"],
            "password"=>$config["mailPass"]
        );
```

This will use TLS instead of SSL. Give it a try.

Comment: As I've said, openssl is already enabled. That's not the issue.

Comment: Well, now I get a different error:  `[message] => authentication failure [SMTP: STARTTLS failed (code: 220, response: 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS)] [userinfo]` As mentioned, I've verified the credentials work on their own. Some Googling tells me that PearMailer doesn't work well with PHP5.6 and above using TLS; do you have a suggestion of a better smtp system for me to use?

Comment: Hi, check [this post](http://osticket.com/forum/discussion/3422/failed-to-configure-email-smtp-settings), @matuha  reply.

Comment: Thanks, but after your previous edit, I switched over to SwiftMailer instead of PearMailer. After a bit of Googling and disabling of SSL peer verification, I was able to get it all working through SSL :) Your answer pointed me in the right direction, though, so thanks :) 

For those wondering: I'm now using SwiftMailer, and setting the verify_peer and verify_peer_name options in the SSL stream options to false. That seems to do the trick :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck.